# Running Javascript after a ASP.NET postback from a client script block injected from a master page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, postback

I cannot get Javascript to run after a ASP.NET postback from a client script block injected from a master page

Below is my master page logic, and it gets hit on a postback, I have confirmed with a breakpoint.

```
namespace MyAwesomeProjectThatWillTakeOverTheWorldIfNotForThisIssue
{
    public partial class CommonContent : MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), 
            "script", 
            "alert('Success!');", 
            true);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the alert popup only appears on the first load but not on postback.

What am I not doing right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using ASP.NET AJAX, and have a script manager on the page, consider using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()`.

Comment: @Achilles, honestly, I'd be dead in the water without Intellisense, what with the subtle differences between method names and scope (static vs. instance) between `ScriptManager` and `Page.ClientScript`.

Answer (score 1):

If this is an ajax triggered postback you need to use `Scriptmanager.registerstartupscript`

Comment: Try referencing the current child page and pass that into the scriptmanager.